# Rasa not identifying my intent, even when I am copy pasting phrases from nlu.yml

Tags: yaml, rasa, rasa-nlu

I am quite new to Rasa. I am trying to get to identify the "get pictures" internet. This is what my `nlu.yml` looks like for this:

```
- intent: get_picture
  examples: |
    - Can I see a picture
    - Show me a picture
    - I want to see a picture
    - Display a picture
    - Bring up a picture
    - I want to see a picture
```

And this is what `domain.yml` looks like:

```
intents:
  - get_picture
  - greet
  - goodbye
  - affirm
  - deny
  - mood_great
  - mood_unhappy
  - bot_challenge
```

Despite this, Rasa almost always fails to identify the `get_picture` intent, once in a while it does it, but 90% of the time it fails, even if I copy-paste the examples. I did re-train Rasa. What else can I troubleshoot?

Comment: Have you defined the story or rule for the `get_picture` and its response?